# Passing data to all views served by a controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a controller that has two methods, each serving up a different view:

```
class NavController extends Controller {
 public function posts()
 {
  $posts = Post::all();
  $tabs = Tag::all();
  return view('posts')->with('posts', => $posts, 'tags' => $tags);
 }
 public function users()
 {
  $users = User::all();
  $tabs = Tag::all();
  return view('users')->with('users', => $users, 'tags' => $tags);
 }
}
```

I wish to avoid writing the logic for retrieving and passing tags in each and every method and thus I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve the data in one place in the controller and then pass it by default to every view that is served up by this controller.

I think it is worth mentioning, that I DO NOT want to share this data across all views, so that for example,  I could use the tags variable in different controllers to serve tags based on a different logic.

Comment: put `$this->tabs = Tag::all();` on class constructor then use it as `$this->tabs`

Comment: Yes, that's one part of the solution, but is there a way that I can avoid having to explicitly write return 'tags' => $this->tags in each return statement where I am returning a view?

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `View::share` on the class construct function:

```
use View;

class NavController extends Controller {
    function __construct() {
        View::share('tags', Tag::all());
    }
    public function posts()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts')->with('posts', => $posts);
    }
    public function users()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('users')->with('users', => $users);
    }
}
```